# If I create a partition, will it delete all of my files?

Tags: 13.10

I am running windows 8 on my SSD, and I also have a 2TB HDD.  I want to install Ubuntu on the HDD, but I have all of my programs and files on that drive, and am worried that I will lose them all if I create Ubuntu partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create NEW partition on unallocated space. So first of all, you must resize your partition you have on that disc (to a smaller one) .

Then you will have unallocated space, where you can safely create NEW partition for your linux.

You can use gparted in linux, or some windows alternative (partition magic for example).

Comment: Where do I creat that first partition? In Windows 8?

Comment: If you have "all of my programs and files on that drive", that means that you already have some partition on that drive. And I guys its NTFS partition. So you need to resize that partition first. Then you can create new partition. If you are installing ubuntu, you will create that new partition in ubuntu installation, and it will be ext4 partition.

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to shrink my current partition, and am now going to go into the Ubuntu installer and create my Ubuntu system partitions there.

Comment: Is Windows 8 in BIOS or UEFI boot mode. Best if install of Ubuntu also is in same boot mode. If Windows drive is gpt partitioned then it must be UEFI. sudo parted -l will show it.

Answer (score 0):

just make **defragmentation** to your **HDD** then delete some space you need for your ubuntu ,30Gb is good enough , then in ubuntu installation make a **swap partition** 2gb then choose the **options** "use all the free space"